# concurrency issues in eclipselink jpa due to cache data

Tags: jpa, caching, concurrency, eclipselink

I am using eclipseLink JPA and i am using same db for two different EJB applications deployed in two different servers. I am getting concurrency issues due to JPA cache if other application is doing some modification on the same object. Is there any way i can manage this concurrency issues. Using native query for db operations is not an option. I am using oracle db and glassfish server. is there any solution available for this.

Comment: what issues do you have? is it transaction locks? or just inconsistent state of the objects due to cache?

Comment: i am showing one record as list in one app and i updated the same from second app, so in list it is showing the same old value.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain why you have issues:

Imagine you have cached data for object. So the first application will work with that cached data and there are no need to this application to go to database (as it already have the value in memory). It can upgrade that cached data if you will perform another modifying query on the **same** `entityManager`. It in no way can know that the other application changed state of your data.

So isolation level won't help as there will be no read query from first application as it already have cached value. And as far as `entityManager` know is only the operations from that same manager. It have no way to know about another `entityManager` on different application.

The solution is to not to cache. Or you can configure external cache as your second level cache which you can evict from both applications (like hazelcast cache for example).

Comment: what is your take on setting isolation level to serialize , will it help with inconsistent data in cache.

Comment: @VickyRathee I edited the answer as it become more clear to me what you are facing with.